# How to copy Excel chart to new workbook and have it point to data in new worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'm trying to collate a number of Excel workbooks into one file.

However, when I copy a sheet from one of the existing workbooks into the new one, the charts I have created refer to the data in the old workbook rather than the new. To illustrate this, here is the reference to the old workbook data after I moved the entire sheet to the new workbook:

> =SERIES(,'[Economic activity.xlsx]Gross state product'!$M$3:$R$3,'[Economic activity.xlsx]Gross state product'!$M$13:$R$13,1)

Is there a way to copy charts between workbooks so that the charts point to the new (and identical) data in the new worksheet? I'm unable to use any third-party add-ons for this project so am reliant on solutions that can be used within Excel only.

Comment: There is some discussion of this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518900/copy-a-chart-from-one-sheet-to-another-using-the-target-sheet-data-for-the-chart).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look and see if it answers my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem before too, and it's good to know that there's a simple solution as explained on this [Excel help site](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/533802-how-to-copy-chart-and-its-data-to-another-excel-worksheet.html).

The secret is to copy the sheet to a new workbook using the "Move or Copy Sheet..." command under the Edit menu.  This dialog can also be opened by CTRL-clicking on the worksheet tab that you want to copy:

[image]

The "To book:" section lists all open workbooks, and you can choose the location of the new sheet in the list.  The worksheet will be moved to the new location, or copied if the checkbox is checked.

The charts that are copied refer to data in the new workbook.  I've tried this, and it works great!  Good luck.

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you very much!